# Version identifier switch for GNU D Compiler (GDC)

Tags: gcc, d, dmd, gdc

Seems that GDC does not support `-version=<ident>` switch, like DMD does.

`--version` or `-v` do not work either.

How do I instruct compiler to use given version identifier?

Comment: nothing in the `--help`?

Comment: No. GDC has no help for D-specific switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `-fversion` see [the gdc wiki](http://gdcproject.org/wiki/UserDocumentation)

Answer (score 2):

The `gdc` program does not accept parameters in the same way that `dmd` does. If you'd like to use DMD-like parameters with `gdc`, use `gdmd`, a helper script which wraps `gdc` and exposes a `dmd`-like command-line interface. For example, `gdmd` will translate `-version` to `-fversion`.